# Connect SFTP Server by ssh key

Tags: docker, ssh, rsa, sftp

I want to simulate an SFTP server on my local machine inside docker container.

I found this image : https://github.com/atmoz/sftp

And prepared this docker-compose file based on the image's github page.

My docker-compose file is like below;

```
version: "3"

services:
  sftp:
    image: atmoz/sftp
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
    command: foo:pass:1001
    volumes:
      - /$HOME/ftp-server-storage:/home/foo/upload
      - ./../../src/main/resources/ssh-key/app_ssh_key.pub:/home/foo/.ssh/keys/id_rsa.pub:ro
    networks:
      - sam_network

networks:
  sam_network:
    driver: bridge
```

And I have generated RSA key pair with this command ;

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa -f app_ssh_key
```

After that I expect to connect server with that command ;

```
sftp -P 2222 -oIdentityFile=app_ssh_key foo@localhost
```

note; I passed private key file for this param ; **-oIdentityFile=app_ssh_key**

but i am getting this error;

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ED25519 key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:EEzFNVY6jLOSg0gJyprSz6AZKlgar+gHZkreQnaNOeo.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/sam/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ED25519 key in /Users/sam/.ssh/known_hosts:2
ED25519 host key for [localhost]:2222 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
Connection closed
```

I could not imagine what is the problem?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Btw note that the problem is with server's host key, not with your private key/key pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the file `/Users/sam/.ssh/known_hosts`

Or execute ssh like this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no foo@localhost
```